# How do I extract any text preceding a certain node using XPath 1.0?

Tags: xml, xpath, xpath-1.0

I need a single XPath expression to select any text preceding a node, regardless of the structure and hierarchy.
For example, how do I extract text before the node `<target/>` in the following cases:

**Case 1:**

```
<a>1</a>
<b>2</b>
<target/>
```

*Expected result: 2*

**Case 2:**

```
<p>1</p>
<do>
  <bt>2</bt>
</do>
<target/>
```

*Expected result: 2*

**Case 3:**

```
<aa>Text <b>child text</b></aa>
<target/>
```

*Expected result: 'child text' or 'Text child text'*

**Case 4:**

```
<p>Text <b>child text</b> tail</p>
<target/>
```

*Expected result: 'tail', 'text tail' or 'text child text tail'*

And so on, there can be as many cases as possible.
Actually, all that I want is the last character of the preceding text, so it doesn't matter whether the result contains text from any nested intermediate child elements.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
//target/preceding::text()[normalize-space(.) != ''][1]
```

[1] instead of [last()] because preceding orders the nodes backwards. 
And [normalize-space(.) != ''] because we don't want text nodes consisting only of whitespace.

Comment: You should also be able to shorten `normalize-space(.) != ''` to just `normalize-space()`.